# In Bigquery, how to create a select statement where the dataset is determined dynamically using a variable that was selected in the query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following query in Bigquery, which works.

`SELECT a, b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C.D as count) FROM some_other_table;`

I want to replace C with the value of a.
a is a dataset and D is a table. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) to execute a dynamic created query:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(
 CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", (SELECT a FROM some_other_table), ".D")
)
```

That way you can create a query and use the result to join with you `some_other_table`.

But if you want only the row number from the table, the view [`TABLE_STORAGE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_storage_view) can help:

```sql
SELECT a, b, ts.total_rows as d_count 
FROM some_other_table
LEFT JOIN `region-US`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE ts 
  ON ts.table_schema = a AND ts.table_name = 'D'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 'a' in my example was selected at the beginning of the query. That's what I want to replace C with. Its' a matter of how to take it from the select phrase at the beginning, and use it later on in the overall query. I may be missing something but I don't see how your example demonstrates this. I apologize if I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: In other words, I now know how to create a dynamic query, (thanks to you) but I don't know how to select a from one table and then use a later in the query, like the example I showed above.

Comment: You cannot use a field from select as a input to a FROM clause, so you will need rethink the way the query was structured. An option is use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to build the dynamic query and then join the result with your table. But if you want only the row number from the tables, another option is use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` view and join with your table.

Comment: Thanks Damião. Very helpful!

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to get is the number of tables per schema, not the number of rows per table. The above does not accomplish this. i can first get all the schema names and then do a query for each one, getting the number of tables, but this  takes too long to run.

Comment: In the question you are trying to count the rows of the table. Can you add a sample of your input and the expected output? Also, the view `TABLE_STORAGE` has all datasets and tables from the specific region. If you aggregate by the dataset you can count the number of tables